# How to make masonry layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create masonry layout through  flexbox.Child element should appear in the following order and also the child are in diffrent height and same width. I am using lazy loading.

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Comment: Make html and css snippet.

Comment: After searching "masonry layout css web design" (because I had never heard the term 'masonry layout' before) I found out a few things: Masonry layout is what I would have called 'Pinterest layout' yesterday. Thanks for teaching me a new term. Previous questions about flexbox masonry layout * https://stackoverflow.com/q/28681572/7382273 * https://stackoverflow.com/q/20977390/7382273

Comment: You can't really if 3 is taller than 4 for example or if 1 is taller than 2, then 4 won't be displayed right below 2.

Answer (score 5):

Technically it's possible with `flex-flow: column-wrap`, but you would need to know the height of the container, so items can wrap properly, plus that you would need to reorder flex items since the default order is vertical.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  color: white;
  background: #e91e63;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.c2 {
  order: 4;
  height: 100px;
}

.c3 {
  order: 2;
  height: 100px;
}

.c4 {
  order: 5;
  height: 200px;
}

.c5 {
  order: 3;
}

.c6 {
  order: 6;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell c1">1</div>
  <div class="cell c2">2</div>
  <div class="cell c3">3</div>
  <div class="cell c4">4</div>
  <div class="cell c5">5</div>
  <div class="cell c6">6</div>
</div>
```

For others ending up in this question looking for a css-only masonry solution, I recommend the following answer by Michael_B (the only and most complete at the moment):

- [CSS-only masonry layout but with elements ordered horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout-but-with-elements-ordered-horizontally)