# How can I reorder a grid of columns?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, css-multicolumn-layout

What I have is a two-column layout with several items inside:

```css
.grid {
  column-count: 2;
}

.grid-item {
  break-inside: avoid;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/RgdLeZ

Now I need an ability to *reorder* those items inside the columns with CSS only (so they were in a different order on different screen resolutions), so I thought I can do this with:

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  column-count: 2;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  order: 5;
}
```

Obviously, this didn't work and broke the 2-column layout. Anybody tried to solve this before? Any chance I can get this working?

PS: Items on the same line *should not* be of the same height (I could have used simple floats in this case). Sorry for not specifying in the beginning.

Comment: Can you set a height on the container? Is the number of items fixed?

Comment: @Michael_B, yes the number of items is fixed, however their height is not (as well as the height of the container).

Comment: How should the end result look like? What should the order be like?

Comment: I don't think you'll find a way to combine them... are you open to other methods? Is your HTML structure fixed?

Comment: @ovokuro, I am open to any solutions. However the HTML markup is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Without a fixed height on the container, a column of flex items won't know where to wrap. There's nothing to cause a break, so items will continue expanding the single column.

Also, `column-count` and `display: flex` represent two different CSS technologies. `column-count` is not a valid property in a flex container.

CSS Grid Layout may be useful to you:

*re-size the screen width to trigger the media query*

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgdjWQ?editors=1100)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px) {
  .grid-item:nth-child(2) {
    order: 1;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, however items on the same line will be of the same height, right?

Comment: In my example, yes. But grid items can be sized independently. See my answer here: [**Create a Masonry grid with flexbox (or other CSS)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43903119/3597276)

Comment: Your solution is explained very well. Thank you! However, it seems that if I have item content height dynamic (e.g. they are text blocks), it won't work as expected.

Comment: Post a codepen with a complete example and I'll check it out.

Comment: So basically you are right and I was trying to reinvent the masonry layout. Here is a complete example: https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/WOmdQw?editors=1100. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, back to square 1: `column-count` with `order`. LOL. Check out some options that may work for you in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Comment: Thanks, I already understood that it's either to fix the height or the container of try out the JS plugins :-)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use flexbox for this

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.grid-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc( 50% - 5px );
  min-height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(1) {
  order: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
</div>
```

The flex syntax is widely supported and super flexible.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the items in the same line will be of the same height.

Comment: It won't if you use `align-items`. Because the default value here is `stretch`. But you could also set it to `center` or as I did `flex-start`

Comment: I am not sure you are right at this point. No matter the `align-items` value, items on the same line will occupy the same height.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood what you meant. Yes you're right. That is indeed a problem.

Comment: Unless you have two adjacent flexbox columns, of course, which are wrapped in their parent on smartphones...