# How to accomplish a masonry layout like Google Keep with Bulma?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bulma

I'm trying to get something like:

[image: goal]

I'm using Bulma and currently I'm using **Columns** with *is_multiline* option. But the only thing I can get is something like:

[image: what I have now]

I would like to remove the gap between the Cards, I guess using more flexbox options. It has to be responsive as well.

```css
.card-columns {
  column-count: 1;
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.card-columns .card {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.columns-6 {
    column-count: 6;
  }
  .columns-5 {
    column-count: 5;
  }
  .columns-4 {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  .columns-3 {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  .columns-2 {
    column-count: 2;
  }
  .columns-1 {
    column-count: 1;
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .columns-6-mobile {
      column-count: 6;
    }
    .columns-5-mobile {
      column-count: 5;
    }
    .columns-4-mobile {
      column-count: 4;
    }
    .columns-3-mobile {
      column-count: 3;
    }
    .columns-2-mobile {
      column-count: 2;
    }
    .columns-1-mobile {
      column-count: 1;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 769px) { 
    .columns-6-tablet {
      column-count: 6;
    }
    .columns-5-tablet {
      column-count: 5;
    }
    .columns-4-tablet {
      column-count: 4;
    }
    .columns-3-tablet {
      column-count: 3;
    }
    .columns-2-tablet {
      column-count: 2;
    }
    .columns-1-tablet {
      column-count: 1;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 1024px) { 
    .columns-6-desktop {
      column-count: 6;
    }
    .columns-5-desktop {
      column-count: 5;
    }
    .columns-4-desktop {
      column-count: 4;
    }
    .columns-3-desktop {
      column-count: 3;
    }
    .columns-2-desktop {
      column-count: 2;
    }
    .columns-1-desktop {
      column-count: 1;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 1216px) { 
    .columns-6-widescreen {
      column-count: 6;
    }
    .columns-5-widescreen {
      column-count: 5;
    }
    .columns-4-widescreen {
      column-count: 4;
    }
    .columns-3-widescreen {
      column-count: 3;
    }
    .columns-2-widescreen {
      column-count: 2;
    }
    .columns-1-widescreen {
      column-count: 1;
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 1408px) { 
    .columns-6-fullhd {
      column-count: 6;
    }
    .columns-5-fullhd {
      column-count: 5;
    }
    .columns-4-fullhd {
      column-count: 4;
    }
    .columns-3-fullhd {
      column-count: 3;
    }
    .columns-2-fullhd {
      column-count: 2;
    }
    .columns-1-fullhd {
      column-count: 1;
    }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card-columns columns-6-fullhd columns-5-widescreen columns-4-desktop columns-3-tablet columns-2-mobile">
    <div class="card card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    <div class="card card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </div>
    <div class="card card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>
    <div class="card card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    <div class="card card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
    <div class="card card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>
    <div class="card card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </div>
    <div class="card card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I tried one of the solution under and it's not working above 4 columns. I updated the snippet.

Comment: Is JavaScript an option here? It's trivial with that, otherwise see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901955/create-a-masonry-grid-with-flexbox-or-other-css which is basically this. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout

Comment: Did you consider `css grids` or are you looking for a fully cross browser solution.

Comment: @BobbyAxe An important caveat for CSS Grid layout is that it only works for a masonry layout if you know the dimensions of each box beforehand; it doesn't work dynamically. That may not be an issue here, but I feel it ought to be mentioned just in case.

Comment: @BobbyAxe No I didn't but it seems to be a good solution for me because I'm gonna know the dimensions of each box.

Answer (score 6):

In your case i think you should use the column an make multiple **css** class and with the help of media you can set the column number as you like, Try this solution hope it will help :

```css
.card-columns {
    column-count: 1;
    column-gap: 1.5rem;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.card-columns .card {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.columns-6 {
   column-count: 6;
}
.columns-5 {
   column-count: 5;
}
.columns-4 {
   column-count: 4;
}
.columns-3 {
   column-count: 3;
}
.columns-2 {
   column-count: 2;
}
.columns-1 {
   column-count: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .columns-6-sm {
    column-count: 6;
  }
  .columns-5-sm {
    column-count: 5;
  }
  .columns-4-sm {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  .columns-3-sm {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  .columns-2-sm {
    column-count: 2;
  }
  .columns-1-sm {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .columns-6-md {
    column-count: 6;
  }
  .columns-5-md {
    column-count: 5;
  }
  .columns-4-md {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  .columns-3-md {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  .columns-2-md {
    column-count: 2;
  }
  .columns-1-md {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) { 
  .columns-6-lg {
    column-count: 6;
  }
  .columns-5-lg {
    column-count: 5;
  }
  .columns-4-lg {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  .columns-3-lg {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  .columns-2-lg {
    column-count: 2;
  }
  .columns-1-lg {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
  .columns-6-xl {
    column-count: 6;
  }
  .columns-5-xl {
    column-count: 5;
  }
  .columns-4-xl {
    column-count: 4;
  }
  .columns-3-xl {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  .columns-2-xl {
    column-count: 2;
  }
  .columns-1-xl {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://bulma.io/css/bulma-docs.min.css?v=201810132054" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card-columns  columns-6-xl columns-5-lg columns-4-md columns-3-sm ">

    <div class="card card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>

    <div class="card card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </div>

    <div class="card card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>

    <div class="card card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>

    <div class="card card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>

    <div class="card card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>

    <div class="card card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </div>

    <div class="card card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>

    <div class="card card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
    
        <div class="card card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>

    <div class="card card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </div>

    <div class="card card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>

    <div class="card card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>

    <div class="card card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>

    <div class="card card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>

    <div class="card card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </div>

    <div class="card card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>

    <div class="card card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to have up to 6 columns for big screens and it's not working!

Comment: just add **6 columns classes** it will be easy if you are using **sass** but i will edit the my answer !! and try again

Comment: I did update my snippet above and it's not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: you need to set also the **classes** inside the **Media Query**,  i did update on my answer check it

Comment: I did it, it seems I did the exact same thing, what am I missing!?

Comment: at this point the children will be filled from left to right, if you will add more children it will look perfect

Comment: Okay that's why. When I add more children it's working as expected. The thing is I need to be able to display correctly even just few cards. I need something consistant. Maybe with Grid?

Comment: This is how **masonry layout  based columns works** it will fill the first column then pass to the next column !! or maybe use some **js** to render it to row

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking for this, please have a look at the below working snippet.

```html
<link href="https://bulma.io/css/bulma-docs.min.css?v=201810132054" rel="stylesheet" />

<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile">
    <div class="column is-one-fifth-widescreen is-one-quarter-desktop is-one-third-tablet is-half-mobile">
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-one-fifth-widescreen is-one-quarter-desktop is-one-third-tablet is-half-mobile">
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-one-fifth-widescreen is-one-quarter-desktop is-one-third-tablet is-half-mobile">
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-one-fifth-widescreen is-one-quarter-desktop is-one-third-tablet is-half-mobile">
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">There are many variations</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bd-klmn">
        <div class="card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated answer based on updated question requirement, just a minor update to the column class and we are done

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
  .mb-medium { margin-bottom: 1.5rem }
</style>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile">
    <div class="column is-one-fifth-widescreen is-one-quarter-desktop is-one-third-tablet is-half-mobile">
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-one-fifth-widescreen is-one-quarter-desktop is-one-third-tablet is-half-mobile">
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-one-fifth-widescreen is-one-quarter-desktop is-one-third-tablet is-half-mobile">
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-one-fifth-widescreen is-one-quarter-desktop is-one-third-tablet is-half-mobile">
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">There are many variations</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-medium">
        <div class="card-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I updated my snippet for you to see that I want to have it responsive depending on the device I'm using.

Comment: @Cyril, please have a look at the above code based on updated requirement, hope it helps :)

Comment: It's a good start but it doesn't work as expected. There is no way to have 5 columns. With 3 columns, there are some non expected gaps.