# CSS Layout - Float: ...up?

Tags: css, layout, css-float

Is there a technique (codified or hacky) to get floated blocks to fill-in upwards as well as their float direction.

So that something like -

[image: Image 1]

Becomes

[image]

I realize this is accomplished by javascript libraries like [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com).

Just wondering if there are any CSS approaches to accomplish this or something similar.

---

Related codepen
https://codepen.io/2nj2nu7p9oVLGXKS4tIpu8eILcmoXg/pen/QOdmqw

```
body * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 500px;
    background: limegreen;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.block {
    height: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px;

    &:nth-child(even) {
        background: blue;
        height: 150px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use Flexbox?

Comment: @ovokuro Sure! (or even Grid) If you have a flexbox technique to accomplish this please including it in an answer.

Comment: This question looks similar --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668548/how-do-you-float-elements-without-a-vertical-gap/25668648#25668648

Comment: @ovokuro You're right, this is a duplicate. You can close if you don't think someone may search for it with the same terminology I used in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply just made any lightblue (odd) elements `float: left` and any blue (even) elements `float: right`

How does this look:

```css
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  background: limegreen;
}

.block {
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 250px;
  border: solid 2px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.block:nth-child(even) {
  float: right;
  background: blue;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```